# how to cancel download of iOS7 on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I started to download iOS7 from my iPhone 4, and then I read about lots of lag and battery issues. I'd love to try iOS7 but since I won't be able downgrade to iOS6 I'd like to cancel the download. The problem is I don't know how.

I've only been able to stop the download by disabling Wi-Fi.

How can I cancel the download of iOS7? Am I doomed to never be able to use Wi-Fi again?

Comment: You could let the download finish and try these steps - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104318/how-to-delete-the-ios7-install-package-on-iPhone but I can't vouch for the force reset portion of the answer even though it seems plausible that it might work.

Comment: Thanks but that is quite risky... what if I end up with iOS7 installed? :S

Comment: You are one restore away from iOS 7 as it stands. You might just have to let the download finish and hope you don't install it when it prompts you.

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80338/stop-new-ios-auto-download-on-ipad

Answer (score 1):

You can probably back up your iPhone with iTunes and then restore that backup, and that should cancel the update.

`Restore Back Up` and not `Restore iPhone`

**There is another way too, which just worked for me: your iPhone can't install the update if it doesn't have the free space available, and this is a pretty big update.  You can simply copy a bunch of large files to your iPhone (e.g., lots of music or audiobooks) and the update will stop and you will get a message saying that the download cannot finish installing due to lack of space.  This essentially stops the update (and then you can go back in and immediately remove the big files that you moved on there).

Comment: Have you had a restore work to iOS 6 in the last week? Without a prior jailbreak I don't see how that wouldn't also upgrade by forcing iOS 7 to be restored. See [this other thread for details](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102398/how-can-i-prevent-a-forced-ios7-upgrade-when-restoring-iphone-4s-from-backup)

Comment: I already tried this, but iTunes will insist on restoring from the latest update which is iOS 7.0.2

Comment: By restore I did not mean a complete restore, just the back up restore.

Comment: Of course if you restore your iPhone it will prompt for iOS 7.0.2, and you cannot downgrade for sure without jailbreak.